# Leaflet: Create layers from geojson "properties"?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layer

I've new to mapping, and I've started creating my map following the documentations and tutorials on http://leafletjs.com. So far so good, I've manage to create a map, add a lot of geosjon data from geojson.io that dislay "popupContent" in a popup. And it works.

But I can't understand how create a few layers to sort all those markers. What I want is too use the "properties" to do it. I have properties named "status" with a values "done", "new" and "active".

Like so:

```
"type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "popupContent": "content",
    "marker-color": "#FFFFFF",
    "title": "title of project",
    "status": "active
```

Is that possible? To create a 3 layers based on "status" properties?

If you need the html file to look at, say so and I can add it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`filter` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter) of `L.geoJson` to create separate layers based on the feature properties. Just specify a function that will return `true` for the features you want included in each layer:

```js
var activeLayer = L.geoJson(yourGeoJson, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.status === "active");
  }
}).addTo(map);

var newLayer = L.geoJson(yourGeoJson, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.status === "new");
  }
}).addTo(map);

var doneLayer = L.geoJson(yourGeoJson, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.status === "done");
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out

Comment: is it possible to make the code above 'dynamic' somehow, i.e. add a layer based for all unique values of `feature.properties.status` ? (three in the case above)